# How to set border color of input field for only numeric values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to set border color of input field to green but only in case when the value in this field is a number. How can I do this?  Here is my html:

```
  <div class="well">
            <input type="text" class="field" value="1245"/><br/><br/>
            <input type="text" class="field" value="efg#21"/><br/><br/>
            <input type="text" class="field" value="34536"/><br/><br/>
            <input type="text" class="field" value="abcd"/><br/><br/>
            <input type="text" class="field" value="12asd"/><br/><br/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Could you suggest a valid js/jquery code for this?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 3):

I'd combine regex with jQuery.  This also responds to input from the user.

```js
function validate() {
  $("input").each(function () {
    if ($(this).val().match("^[0-9]+$")) {
      $(this).css("border-color","green")
    } else {
      $(this).css("border-color","red")
    }
  });
}

$("input").on("keyup", validate);
validate()
```

```css
input {
  border-width:1px;
  border-style:solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="well">
    <input type="text" class="field" value="1245"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" class="field" value="efg#21"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" class="field" value="34536"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" class="field" value="abcd"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" class="field" value="12asd"/><br/><br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the callback of the [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function)-function to check the value and set the border accordingly:

```js
$("input").css("border", function() {
  return (!isNaN($(this).val())) ? '1px solid green' : '';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="well">
  <input type="text" class="field" value="1245" />
  <input type="text" class="field" value="efg#21" />
  <input type="text" class="field" value="34536" />
  <input type="text" class="field" value="abcd" />
  <input type="text" class="field" value="12asd" />
</div>
```

---

*Reference*

[isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

[ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)